# Force two JLists to have the same size in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, dimension

Im trying to make a JavaSwing component that swaps items between two JLists. It works fine. But when some item from one list is longer, it changes the sizes to fit the text. I don't want this to happen. I've added JScrollBar to every JLists, and if I resize the Window they appear. But I want the size of the lists to be kept the same.

[Here's a screenshot of my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lah7S.png)
I could not avoid to notice that vertical Jpanel's size affects how JLists are drawn. See 3rd screenshot, the panel is smaller and it works fine.

Here's some code so you can test it. Try moving every long entry to one table and see what happens.

```
package table.resize.problem;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * @author theasdas
 */
public class TableResizeProblem {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame window = new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    //components:
    private JList list1 = new JList();
    private JList list2 = new JList();
    private DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
    private DefaultListModel model2 = new DefaultListModel();
    private JButton btnMove = new JButton("Move");
    //variables:
    private int selectedList = 0; //defines which list is focused by the user

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        //initial configuration
        configureSelf();
        configureComponents();
        setListeners();
        placeComponents();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Configure this component.
     */
    private void configureSelf() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setSize(600, 800);
    }

    /**
     * Configure other components.
     */
    private void configureComponents() {
        //lists
        list1.setModel(model1);
        list2.setModel(model2);
        //models
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            model1.addElement("item " + (i + 1));
            model1.addElement("looooong item" + (i + 1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            model2.addElement("item " + (i + 1));
            model2.addElement("looooong item" + (i + 1));
        }
        //button
        btnMove.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void setListeners() {

        //list focus listener
        FocusListener onFocus = new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                checkFocus((JList) fe.getSource());
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                //do nothing
            }
        };
        //add listener to lists
        this.list1.addFocusListener(onFocus);
        this.list2.addFocusListener(onFocus);

        //button action listener
        ActionListener onClick = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                swapItem();
            }
        };
        this.btnMove.addActionListener(onClick);
    }

    /**
     * Checks which list is focused.
     *
     * @param list
     */
    private void checkFocus(JList list) {

        if (list == list1) {
            list2.clearSelection();
            selectedList = 1;
            btnMove.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            list1.clearSelection();
            selectedList = 2;
            btnMove.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap an item between lists.
     */
    private void swapItem() {

        if (selectedList == 0 && (list1.getSelectedValue() == null || list2.getSelectedValue() == null)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JPanel(), "Bruh...", "Bruh moment has been achieved.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        } else {
            if (selectedList == 1) {
                model2.addElement(list1.getSelectedValue());
                model1.removeElement(list1.getSelectedValue());
            } else {
                model1.addElement(list2.getSelectedValue());
                model2.removeElement(list2.getSelectedValue());
            }
        }
        selectedList = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Places components in a grid.
     */
    private void placeComponents() {
        GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();

        //(0, 0) list1
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 0;
        g.weightx = 1;
        g.weighty = 1;
        g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        g.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        this.add(list1, g);
        //(1, 0) list 2
        g.gridx = 1;
        this.add(list2, g);
        //(0, 1) button
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 1;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        g.weighty = 0;
        g.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        this.add(btnMove, g);
    }

}
```

So, what am I lacking?

Comment: How about an [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question to add one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following.  I made some changes.

- It is not a good idea to extend JFrame.  So I extended JPanel and added it to the frame.
- I made each JList large enough to sit side by side and also for room on the bottom for the button.
- And your JList and Model are generic types so I added those as well. This uses `BorderLayout` which seems to work fine.
- I also overrode getInsets for the JLists and added a border to delineate them.

I also added a few comments in the code. Please let me know if this does not do what you intended.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

/**
 * @author theasdas
 */
public class TableResizeProblem {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame window = new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MainFrame extends JPanel {

    //components:
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    private JList<String> list1 = new JList<>() {
        public Insets getInsets() {
            return new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        }
    };
    private JList<String> list2 = new JList<>() {
        public Insets getInsets() {
            return new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        }
    };

    private DefaultListModel<String> model1 = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private DefaultListModel<String> model2 = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JButton btnMove = new JButton("Move");
    //variables:
    private int selectedList = 0; //defines which list is focused by the user

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(this);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        list1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,600));
        list2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,600));


        list1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        list2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        add(list1,BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(list2,BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(btnMove,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        configureComponents();
        setListeners();
        // pack the frame and invoke the layouts
        frame.pack();
        // center the frame on the screen.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    /**
     * Configure other components.
     */
    private void configureComponents() {
        //lists
        list1.setModel(model1);
        list2.setModel(model2);
        //models
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            model1.addElement("item " + (i + 1));
            model1.addElement("looooong item" + (i + 1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            model2.addElement("item " + (i + 1));
            model2.addElement("looooong item" + (i + 1));
        }
        //button
        btnMove.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void setListeners() {

        //list focus listener
        FocusListener onFocus = new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                checkFocus((JList<String>) fe.getSource());
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                //do nothing
            }
        };
        //add listener to lists
        this.list1.addFocusListener(onFocus);
        this.list2.addFocusListener(onFocus);

        //button action listener
        ActionListener onClick = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                swapItem();
            }
        };
        this.btnMove.addActionListener(onClick);
    }

    /**
     * Checks which list is focused.
     *
     * @param list
     */
    private void checkFocus(JList list) {

        if (list == list1) {
            list2.clearSelection();
            selectedList = 1;
            btnMove.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            list1.clearSelection();
            selectedList = 2;
            btnMove.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap an item between lists.
     */
    private void swapItem() {

        if (selectedList == 0 && (list1.getSelectedValue() == null || list2.getSelectedValue() == null)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JPanel(), "Bruh...", "Bruh moment has been achieved.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        } else {
            if (selectedList == 1) {
                model2.addElement(list1.getSelectedValue());
                model1.removeElement(list1.getSelectedValue());
            } else {
                model1.addElement(list2.getSelectedValue());
                model2.removeElement(list2.getSelectedValue());
            }
        }
        selectedList = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't work. Now the tables do not resize horizontally.

Comment: That's because you said. *But I want the size of the lists to be kept the same.*  Size of `JComponents` includes `width` and `height`.

Comment: Yes, but I want them to be able to resize and change components between tables without them deforming. Anyway, I finally found the way to fix it: instead if setting the LJist preferredSize, I set the JScrollPane preferredSize and left the list's to it's default state..

Comment: Glad you fixed it.